# How to print out a functions return statement in main in C?

Tags: c, arrays, printf, return-value

So I completely forget how to print out a return statement from a different function and display it in my main function. I commented out of my attempt to print the functions return statement. My following code is as follows:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[1024];
  int i;
  int num;
  int size;
  printf("How large is the Array: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  for( i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
  scanf("%d",&array[i]);
  }

 printf("\nArray contains: ");

 for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
 {
  printf("%d",array[i]);
 }
 printf("\nSubsequence: ");
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
 {
  //printf("%d",maxArray(max_so_far));
 /// //I want to print max_so_far right here//////
 }
  printf("\n");
 return 0;
```

}

```
int maxArray(int array[], int size)
{
 int max_so_far = 0;
 int max_end = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
 max_end = max_end + array[i];
 if (max_end < 0)
    max_end = 0;
 if(max_so_far < max_end)
   max_so_far = max_end;
   }
   return max_so_far;
}
```

Comment: What will `maxArray` do?

Comment: This is invalid code. The function has to be declared before usage.

Comment: Max array will print the contents of the sum of the subsequence. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Why is not `array[0]` included? Also, Why is it reset when it is `max_end < 0`?

Comment: Probably the logic is incorrect.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY for some reason, that typo explained most of my problems of why I was off by one. The print statements also worked so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("%d",maxArray(arrayYouWantToPass, sizeYouWantToPass));
    /// just call the function with right parameter and print it//////
}
```

just like

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("%d",maxArray(array, 2));
    //printf("%d",maxArray(array, size)); or this if size already have a value 
    /// just call the function with right parameter and print it//////
}
```

but i think there is a problem with your code in maxArray function. you passed an array , and want to return value after. but you put array in a loop. This will only run once because it will return after first loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the print.

```
printf("%d",maxArray(array, size));
```

you needed to include the size, like your fucntion is asking you to, and
put the array on the first parameter.

Comment: you are not puting anything on the variable size. Take care of that before using it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question from the above help, to print out the return statement and call it in main, I had to do so like:

```
printf("\nSubsequence: ");
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
 {
  printf("%d",maxArray(array,num));   //this is the way to print out what I wanted
 }
  printf("\n");
```